# php artisan migrate:install doesn't create the forgotten password table why?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have recently started playing around with `Laravel` and I want to connect it to my php database on the local host . SO I've done all the parts successfully, but I've stocked at the creating the tables in database using terminal. I went to my project directory  and ran the following command:

```
hp artisan migrate:install migrations
```

which create my migration table in database. Then I ran the following command:

```
 php artisan migrate:install
```

and the output I received was:  `Migration table created successfully.`
Then I went to my `phpmyadmin` to see every thing is there but then I realised that my user table and migration table are there but the table for the forgotten password was missing. So I ran the same command again and here is what I get the image.

Where am I making my mistake? can I create the table manually?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `php artisan make:auth` on this installation yet?

Also, make sure your `App\User` model implements the  `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword` property.

**app/models/User.php**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract,
CanResetPasswordContract {
// ...
```

Comment: oh no I didn't but now I deleted the table of Users and then ran `php artisan make:auth` and then then copy pasted the heading u've just gave me and reinstall them again `php artisan migrate` but I still get my user table and not the other one

Comment: Which tables is specified at `/app/config/auth.php` in `'reminder' => array( 'email' => '', 'table' => 'HERE?' )`

Comment: See here for some other ideas: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/artisan-migrate-password-reset-table?page=1